# How to unpack column values in data frame as column names in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe

I have a data frame as below

```
Name Place                Age
Joe  [NYC, Paris, Madrid]  33
Mary [Rome]                30
Jack [Paris, Madrid]       35
```

I want the output in a data frame as

```
Name NYC Paris Madrid Rome Age
Joe  Yes  Yes   Yes     No  33
Mary  No   No    No    Yes  30
Jack  No  Yes   Yes     No  35
```

I have tried to do this various ways like

```
cities = ['NYC', 'Rome', 'Madrid', 'Paris']
for city in cities:
  df_city = df.apply(lambda x: x in city if x==x else False)


df[city]=df_city   //Creating a column name based on the city. But this gives an error stating array size doesn’t match
```

I tried also the following

```
if(city=='NYC'):
  df[city].append("True")
elif(city=='Paris'):
  df[city].append("True")
elif(city=='Madrid'):
  df[city].append("True")
else(city=='Rome'):
  df[city].append("True")
```

But this only gives me

```
Name NYC Paris Madrid Rome Age
Joe   No  Yes    No     No  33
Mary  No   No    No     No  30
Jack  No  Yes    No     No  35
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, these are the step for the manipulation.

1. apply fill function  row wise of the subdf dataframe
2. Iterate over values of the each row inside the fill function (which are city names)
3. check if row value (cities) matches with bool_cities column name (bool_cities columns are same city names)
4. For example “NYC is is located at 0th row and 0th column of the subdf.so we can say that “NYC”  should be in 0th row.
   so we can fill bool_cities df, “NYC” column’s 0th position as True

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([["Joe", ["NYC", "Paris", "Madrid"] , 33],
                   ["Mary", ["Rome"] ,30],
                   ["Jack", ["Paris", "Madrid"],35]])
df.columns = ["Name","Place","age"]


subdf = pd.DataFrame(df["Place"].to_list())
unique_cities = list(pd.unique(subdf.values.ravel()))
unique_cities.remove(None)
bool_cities = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(df),len(unique_cities))),columns=unique_cities)

def fill(x):
    for i in x.values:
        if i in list(bool_cities.columns):
            bool_cities.loc[x.name,i]=1

subdf.apply(lambda x: fill(x),axis=1) 
bool_cities=bool_cities.astype(bool)
bool_cities = bool_cities.replace({True:"Yes", False:"No"})
result = pd.concat([df.drop("Place",axis=1),bool_cities],axis=1)
```

output

```
   Name  age  NYC Paris Madrid Rome
0   Joe   33  Yes   Yes    Yes   No
1  Mary   30   No    No     No  Yes
2  Jack   35   No   Yes    Yes   No
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked. Do you have any documentation / explanation about what exactly the user defined function fill is doing?

Comment: @user3423407 I have added the explanation